# Change handler for a property without a name

Tags: javascript, aurelia

Consider the following list:

*fields.html*

```
<div repeat.for="f of fields">
    ${f.name}: <input value.bind="f.value">
</div>
```

*fields.js*

```
class Fields
{
    fields = [{
        name: "First name",
        value: "Jack"
    }, {
        name: "Surname",
        value: "Giant slayer"
    }];
}
```

I want to save the list once it is changed (maybe after few seconds, like throttle). How can I introduce a handler to `Fields` class to be called once one of the textboxes are changed? And I'm not talking about the `blur` event handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save when the DOM `input` event is fired. Use the `debounce` binding behavior to rate-limit the saves.

**Here's an example: https://gist.run?id=26ea2f5e3a2c35ecd96ff9aa579a893f**

**app.html**

```html
<template>
  <form input.delegate="save() & debounce:500">
    <label repeat.for="f of fields">
      ${f.name}: <input value.bind="f.value">
    </label>
  </form>

  <pre><code>${log}</code></pre>
</template>
```

**app.js**

```js
export class App {
  fields = [
    { name: "First name", value: "Jack" },
    { name: "Surname",    value: "Giant slayer" }
  ];

  log = '';

  save() {
    this.log += `Saved: ${JSON.stringify(this.fields)}\n`;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly what I want. As I tested it, it does not need to be a `form` tag and any tag will do, right? In your Gist the form tag works perfectly. But in my code as soon as I type in the form tag, the following error happens: `ERROR [app-router] RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`. Not that I'm asking how to fix it, but if you think I should report it somewhere, please let me know.

Comment: Right- doesn't need to be a form tag. I used form and label only for semantic reasons